# Running identical queries in sysbench

Tags: mysql, concurrency, benchmark

When benchmarking using sysbench and utilizing concurrency (multiple threads) for example on a table with 1,000,000 records, does sysbench run "identical" queries in a loop on the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create several test types with sysbench, but if you look at the typical OLTP tests for [SELECTS](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sysbench-developers/sysbench/0.5/view/head:/sysbench/tests/db/select.lua) and [INSERTS](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sysbench-developers/sysbench/0.5/view/head:/sysbench/tests/db/insert.lua) you will see that the queries executed are **similar in pattern, but with random values for each query** (not identical every time).

If they were identical (something that you could test if you wanted), structures like the query cache and buffer pool would be very effective, invalidating the reason for the stress test.